# Difference Betweeen SIP and HTTP Response 407 code?

Tags: http, protocols, sip, rfc

What is the difference between SIP response code 407 and HTTP response code 407 (Proxy Authentication Required)?

Comment: What is the reason for close ?

Comment: If you feel that you have to slap non-programming-related on your question, maybe you should think of a better way to ask your question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this PDF](http://www.tech-invite.com/SIP/Archi/Ti-SIP-Protocol-Structure.pdf), you get (or send) a 407 with SIP when you cannot authenticate the originator because no credentials are provided.

An HTTP 407 is, as you said, given when proxy authentication is required - essentially, they're the same.

Comment: SIP's 407 says "you need to authenticate to use this communication channel" (as opposed to SIP's 401 - "you need to authenticate to contact this user agent") so yes, SIP's 407 and HTTP's 407 are identical in function.